# New-AzRoleAssignment : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ObjectId'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-container-registry

Earlier below was the code and it was working with AzureRm

```
$registry = Get-AzureRmContainerRegistry -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $acrName
# Get the existing service principal; need its 'ObjectId' value
# when assigning the role to the principal in a subsequent command.
$sp = Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName $appId
$role = New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $sp.Id -RoleDefinitionName $role -Scope $registry.Id
```

Now with latest Azure Module Az it does not work.

```
$registry = Get-AzContainerRegistry -ResourceGroupName "somenamee" -Name "acrcontainername"
$sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName "............."
$role = New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $sp.Id -RoleDefinitionName 'acrpull' -Scope $registry.Id
```

Errors:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ObjectId'. The     argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:40
+ $role = New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $sp.Id -RoleDefinitionName $ro ...
+                                        ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-AzRoleAssignment],     ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :         ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand
```

Comment: When I tried below code , "$sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId 9719c54e-15ca-4911-a6fb-..........."    I got below errors PS C:\windows\system32> $sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId 9719c54e-15ca-4911-a6fb-a23653284ed1
Get-AzADServicePrincipal : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
At line:1 char:7
+ $sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId 9719c54e-15ca-4911-a6fb ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-AzADServicePrincipal], Exception
    + FullyQual

Comment: I have service principal "acr..........." that appid and secret key, and now want to assign "AcrImageSigner" role of azure container registry to this service principal "acr..........."   How can i do this.

Comment: Do you use the `AzureRm` and `Az` commands on the same service principal?

Comment: AzureRm I have used username and password and for Az I am using service principal

Comment: How can I assign Role to Container registry using App Name. I can do this in Azure portal. But I need help in powershell to do it

Comment: Could you let me know if my reply solved your issue or not? If it solved your issue, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

> AzureRm I have used username and password and for Az I am using service principal

If you use the Azure powershell with a service principal, you need to give the permissions to your service principal.

There are two options(you need to login to the azure portal as a `Global administrator` in your AAD tenant, I recommend you to use the option 2):

1.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` -> `Roles and administrators` -> click `Global administrator` -> `Add assignments` -> add your service principal.

2.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` -> `App registrations` -> find the AD App of your service principal and add the `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission of `Azure Active Directory Graph` like below.

[image]

[image]

---

After giving the permissions in AAD, the command `Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId xxxxx` will work. To use `New-AzRoleAssignment`, your service prinicpal should be an `Owner` in your subscription or ContainerRegistry. If you don't give the `Owner` role, it will not be able to assign the role assignment.

Navigate to the subscription or ContainerRegistry in the portal as an `Owner` ->  `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add`-> `Add role assignment` -> add your service principal as an `Owner`, details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Navigate to the Azure Active Directory -> Roles and administrators -> click Global administrator -> Add assignments -> add your service principal.

You cannot add service principals to global administrators.

> 2.Navigate to the Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> find the AD App of your service principal and add the
> Application.ReadWrite.All permission of Azure Active Directory Graph
> like below.

I tried adding the following permissions:

Azure Active Directory Graph

- Application.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All

Microsoft Graph

- Application.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All

Az module 4.7 still has error with Get-AzADServicePrincipal under powershell 7.